# Get AsyncTask's result without blocking the thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface, android-asynctask

I have the code that sends requests to REST API in AsyncTask.
Also, I have a ProgressDialog initialization in `preExecute()` and its dismission in `postExecute()`.

I want ProgressDialog to show an indeterminate spinner (you know, that loading animation), but I need to get a result too. `get()` blocks the main thread where I'm invoking it in - what's the workaround for that case?

Main thread (main activity)

```
LoginTask task_login = new LoginTask();
                AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> response = task_login.execute(et_username.getText().toString(), et_password.getText().toString());
                try {
                    JSONObject json = response.get();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, json.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Interrupted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

AsyncTask (dummy doInBackground):

```
public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
    private LoginTask self = this;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.context,
                "Logging in...", "");
        progressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL,
                MainActivity.context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.string.dialog_button_cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                self.cancel(true);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);

        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Comment: Show your code here. So that i can suggest you updates.

Comment: By the way why you are implementing Api call by HTTP, when there are well known libraries Volley & Retrofit.

Comment: I use okhttp to send requests

Comment: why are you using `.get();` when you can get the data in the onPostExecute? You're completely ruining the purpose of an AsyncTask.

Comment: Welp, I didn't know that I should put the code into postExecute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at the usage of AsyncTask https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#usage

There is a callback function `onPostExecute` which returns (as parameter) the value you requested:

```
private class RestTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(Object... args) {
        // this happend on background thread
        return downloadData();
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // this happend on UI thread
        showSpinner();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // this happend on UI thread
        hideSpinner();
        doSomethingWithDownloadResult(result);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
new RestTask().execute()
```

---

As you edited the question, this:

```
try {
    JSONObject json = response.get();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, json.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Interrupted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

should be called in previous Tasks `onPostExecute` method, this way you will not block you UI with `get` method waiting on login result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AsyncTask's onProgressUpdate() method to perform the actions on the UI thread (such as showing or updating a loading animation) while doInBackGround() does the background work on another thread.

Basically you invoke the [publishProgress()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#publishProgress(Progress...)) method from within doInBackGround(), which in turn calls onProgressUpdate().

Check out the [Android reference page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) on AsyncTask for an example.

Answer (score 0):

1 - You can use a callback method. 
but keep in mind you should call it in your main thread.

2 - you can use `LocalBroadcastManager` in order to send your result through `Intent`.

3 - you might want to use in application messaging libraries which are more reliable in my opinion. one example which I use very often is `EventBus`.